# How to pipe hashtable to cmdlet expecting dictionary?

Tags: c#, powershell

I wrote a small PowerShell cmdlet in C# that is expecting a parameter of a Dictionary. How do I structure a HashTable (or other object) in a PowerShell script so that I can pass it as a parameter to my cmdlet?

I've tried creating a HashTable in my PowerShell script as follows:

```
$dic = @{
    "Key1" = 1,2,3;
    "Key2" = "A","B","C";
}
```

And then piping this to my cmdlet:

```
$props | Add-Properties
```

My cmdlet:

```
public class AddProps : PSCmdlet {
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true, Mandatory = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object[]> Props {get; set;}

    protected override void ProcessRecord() {
        DoSomethingWithProps(Props);
    }
}
```

I expected to be able to write a short PowerShell script like this:

```
$dic = @{
    "Key1" = 1,2,3;
    "Key2" = "A","B","C";
}

$props | Add-Properties
```

However, when I try this I get this error:

> The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input

I checked the type of `$props` and it is indeed a `HashTable`. After looking at other questions related to this pipeline input issue and how to build a `HashTable` in PowerShell, I am still at a loss for what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this using interfaces instead if you don't want to change the type to `Hashtable`:

```
PS> [hashtable].GetInterfaces()

IsPublic IsSerial Name
-------- -------- ----
True     False    IDictionary
True     False    ICollection
True     False    IEnumerable
True     False    ISerializable
True     False    IDeserializationCallback
True     False    ICloneable
```

---

```
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true, Mandatory = true)]
public IDictionary Props { get; set; }
```

Comment: I modified the `Props` property to use type `IDictionary<string, object[]>` but still receive the same error when using the updated module

Comment: @pavuxun You don't specify the K,V when defining the interface.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I was still using the `Generic` type which does require the K,V